# Change text onclick button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the button to change text onclick, at the same time it also opens the menu. The menu is working and is opening onclick but the text on the button is not.

Is it maybe troubleshooting with the part that opens the menu?
I can't find why its not working.

The button

```
<button type="button" id="showRight" onClick="click()">Tools</button>
```

The script:

```
<script>
    var menuLeft = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s1' ),
        menuRight = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s2' ),
        menuTop = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s3' ),
        menuBottom = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s4' ),
        showRight = document.getElementById( 'showRight' ),
        body = document.body;

    showRight.onclick = function() {
        classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
        classie.toggle( menuRight, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    };

    function click()
    {
        var change = document.getElementById("showRight");
        if (change.value == "Tools")
        {
            change.value = "X";
        }
        else
        {
            change.value = "Tools";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: And `classie` is never defined

Comment: added the script line which does now

Comment: Why are you calling two different functions, two different ways, on the same event on the same element?

Comment: @marjin is it working now?

Comment: If you're using jQuery why are you doing things like `document.getElementById('showRight')` instead of `$('showRight')`? If you're using jQuery, **use** jQuery.

Comment: @eeetee I just combined them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not `change.value` it's `change.textContent`  or `change.innerText` if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks, I combined both functions and used textContent instead now its working

Answer (score 1):

When you add events, you are overriding the the inline click attribute.

You should be using addEventListener

```
showRight.addEventListener("click", function() {} );
```

Personally I would combine both of the methods into one.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that click is a keyword and cant be used for the function name.
If you simply change the function name to showRight_click() and update your onclick to match it works just fine.

Comment: It can be used as function name. Your guess is wrong. Just try it yourself.

Comment: This was not a guess. I did try it before I posted an answer and it never fired the event with function click(). You need to try it.

Comment: :) then was not a guess, but simply lack of knowledge. `click` can be function name, it's not a problem. It didn't work simply because event set up as dom element property `showRight.onclick` overwrites event bound with attribute.